# how work function of magento getviewurl()? and how it fetch $order->getId()?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

how work function of magento getviewurl()? and how it fetch $order->getId()?

```
public function getViewUrl($order)
{

    return $this->getUrl('*/*/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
}
```

i just want to know how it fecth getId() from which table?

Answer (score 1):

Orders data are saved in database tables **sales_flat_order** and **sales_flat_order_item**

Answer (score 0):

If table is all that you want its getting from id from sales_flat_order

But magento follows an eav system and I think you are confused how the order is getting data

If this is the case then you have to get some idea about
Magento model, resource model, collection